# Как привязать ширину колонки одной таблицы к ширине колонки другой таблицы

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid

Есть две таблицы WeeekHeaderGrid и ScheduleGrid. Первая используется для отображения заголовков дней недели, и данные в ней не выводятся. Вторая отображает уроки по дням недели, и в ней уже выводятся данные. Как привязать ширину колонки таблицы WeeekHeaderGrid к ширине колонки таблицы ScheduleGrid. Пытался привязывать через Source, но не сработало. Привожу свой код:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <DataGrid x:Name="WeeekHeaderGrid" Grid.Row="0">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="" Width="{Binding Source={x:Reference ClassName}, Path=ActualWidht, Mode=OneWay}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Понедельник"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>

    <DataGrid x:Name="ScheduleGrid" Grid.Row="1" Language="ru-RU" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectionMode="Single"
              CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserSortColumns="False"
              CellEditEnding="ScheduleGrid_CellEditEnding">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="ClassName" Header="Класс" />
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="1 урок"/>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="2 урок"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

**UPD1**: Обновил код. Теперь мне нужно сложить ширину нескольких столбцов через привязку, чтобы получить ширину столбца дня недели. Но при компиляции вываливается с ошибкой System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: "Данный ключ отсутствует в словаре."
XAML-код:

```
               <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <DataGrid x:Name="WeeekHeaderGrid" Grid.Row="0" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserSortColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="True">
                        <DataGrid.Resources>
                            <customInterface:SumConverter x:Key="WidhtSumConverter"/>
                        </DataGrid.Resources>
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="" Width="{Binding Source={x:Reference ClassName}, Path=Width, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Понедельник">
                                <DataGridTextColumn.Width>
                                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource WidhtSumConverter}">
                                        <Binding Source="{x:Reference Lesson11}" Path="Width" Mode="OneWay"/>
                                        <Binding Source="{x:Reference Lesson12}" Path="Width" Mode="OneWay"/>
                                        <Binding Source="{x:Reference Lesson13}" Path="Width" Mode="OneWay"/>
                                        <Binding Source="{x:Reference Lesson14}" Path="Width" Mode="OneWay"/>
                                        <Binding Source="{x:Reference Lesson15}" Path="Width" Mode="OneWay"/>
                                        <Binding Source="{x:Reference Lesson16}" Path="Width" Mode="OneWay"/>
                                    </MultiBinding>
                                </DataGridTextColumn.Width>
                            </DataGridTextColumn>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Вторник"/>
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
                    <DataGrid x:Name="ScheduleGrid" Grid.Row="1" Language="ru-RU" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectionMode="Single"
                              CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserSortColumns="False"
                              CellEditEnding="ScheduleGrid_CellEditEnding">
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="ClassName" Header="Класс" />
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="Lesson11" Header="1 урок"/>
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="Lesson12" Header="2 урок"/>
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="Lesson13" Header="3 урок"/>
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="Lesson14" Header="4 урок"/>
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="Lesson15" Header="5 урок"/>
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="Lesson16" Header="6 урок"/>
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
                </Grid>
```

Код конвертера:

```
public class SumConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        double val = 0.0;
        double result = 0.0;

        foreach (var txt in values)
        {
            if (double.TryParse(txt.ToString(), out val))
                result += val;
            else
                return "NaN";
        }

        return result;

    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

}
```

Comment: @АндрейNOP. Спасибо, сам не заметил. Обновил свой вопрос - теперь мне нужно сложить ширину нескольких столбцов

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После нескольких попыток смог добиться нужно результата. В XAML-коде нужно сначала произвести инициализацию переменных в ScheduleGrid (дочерняя таблица), а затем уже ссылаться на столбцы из нее в WeeekHeaderGrid (родительская таблица). Студия всеравно будет ругаться на MultiBinding, но компиляция пройдет нормально

```
                    <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <DataGrid x:Name="ScheduleGrid" Grid.Row="1" Language="ru-RU" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectionMode="Single"
                              CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserSortColumns="False"
                              CellEditEnding="ScheduleGrid_CellEditEnding">
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="ClassName" Header="Класс" Binding="{Binding CLASS_NAME}" />
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="Lesson11" Header="1 урок">
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <customInterface:LessonCell Background="Aqua" SubjectName="Русский" TeacherName="Кириллова Р.Б." CabinetName="11" />
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="Lesson12" Header="2 урок"/>
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="Lesson13" Header="3 урок"/>
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="Lesson14" Header="4 урок"/>
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="Lesson15" Header="5 урок"/>
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="Lesson16" Header="6 урок"/>
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>

                    <DataGrid x:Name="WeeekHeaderGrid" Grid.Row="0" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserSortColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="True">
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="" Width="{Binding Source={x:Reference ClassName}, Path=Width, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Понедельник">
                                <DataGridTextColumn.Width>
                                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource WidthConverter}" Mode="TwoWay">
                                        <Binding Source="{x:Reference Lesson11}" Path="ActualWidth" />
                                        <Binding Source="{x:Reference Lesson12}" Path="ActualWidth" />
                                        <Binding Source="{x:Reference Lesson13}" Path="ActualWidth" />
                                        <Binding Source="{x:Reference Lesson14}" Path="ActualWidth" />
                                        <Binding Source="{x:Reference Lesson15}" Path="ActualWidth" />
                                        <Binding Source="{x:Reference Lesson16}" Path="ActualWidth" />
                                    </MultiBinding>
                                </DataGridTextColumn.Width>
                            </DataGridTextColumn>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Вторник"/>
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
                </Grid>
```

Также переписал код конвертера, чтобы он возвращал DataGridLength

```
    public class WidthConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        double totalWidth = 0;

        foreach (double Width in values)
            totalWidth += Width;

        return new DataGridLength(totalWidth);

    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```